# Problems with favicon not showing in Vue CLI 4.4.6 generated proyect

Tags: vue.js, favicon, vue-cli-4

I'm having a big trouble with this proyect generated with the latest version of Vue CLI up to this date. The favicon does not show up, I've deleted previously the */img* folder in the *public* folder, and added my own favicon.png to the index.html file.

When i run the proyect the icon does not show up and checking the client side code, it automatically gets commented as shown in the image.
If I modify the commented line, my custom icon appears correctly, so I want to know how to fix this.

[image: screenshot]

*index.html file*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.png">
    <title> myApp </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but myApp doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Also as you can see in the code, I've erased the `<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %>` that generates initially because it's useless for me.
Big thanks for anyone who can help me!